# Tomcat wont deploy application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment, primefaces

I have web app with primefaces and spring, which is running OK on all dev and test envs, but it stopped running on production servers. NO errors, nothing. I just get this error and i can't understand why it couldn't initialize the web app. This is the INFO:
**INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath**

Comment: i guess there is some library missing

Comment: unfortunately no, the code is coming from the same svn tag. I actually deploy two web apps. First is deployed correctly, but the second is not, while on dev/test envs they both are working fine.

Comment: many there are some extra jars in the tomcat/libs folders. compare them

Comment: The strange thing is that is was working and it just stop working. jars in lib are the same

Comment: Is it possible to be something with the work directory? The deployment guys dont want to delete it and is it possible that the tomcat is broken some how?

Comment: Try using the core distribution and deploy it manually

Comment: Problem solved. The app is using activemq in failover mode and during deployment spring is loading the activemq connection service and the code of activemq was trying to connect to some broker in infinite loop, which was blocking the deployment.